# How to provide my application as a SAAS

Tags: saas

I currently have a few apps that I provide to clients by setting them up on their own website. The app uses their own SQL database to record any transactions.

Recently, the number of customers I supply the app to has increased, leading to a higher maintenance work load as each installation must be managed separately.

I'm ready to move to the next level and want to host the app in a single cloud based environment so that I only have to maintain one instance.  I would then provide access to that app to each client site, for example embed it in an iframe or perhaps deliver it via a sub-domain. I am not sure about where the DB would sit?

However, this is new territory for me and I'm not sure where to begin.  The app is very small and quite simple. I've read a lot of stuff about SAAS but most of it seems quite enterprise level, I'm really looking for a simple and easy to use starting point.

What's the current best practice for this kind of setup and what might be a good guide to read or platform to use?

Comment: What tech stack are you currently using? Are you looking to rebuild from the ground up or try and retrofit your existing app?